# QThreads Vs Pthreads

Tags: qt, pthreads

I have a quick question. I am supposed to create a small multithreaded program to grab data from multiple sensors and I have knowledge of both pthreads and qthreads. I have access to both libraries. personally I am biased towards using Qt because of its design and various functionalities. But is there a significant advantage on using one vs the other?
Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

QThreads are built upon pthreads. They provide an Object Oriented abstraction, making it easier to work with threads. Besides QThreads are portable, they can run on whatever system using the underlying thread system, while pthreads are specific of POSIX systems.

The almost-only disadvantage of using QThreads is that you'll need to link your application against Qt; this dependence could make it a little more difficult to distribute your application.

Comment: Ya.. I was just looking at it and it looks like internally thats how it is done. Thanks peoro. I was actually specifically looking for if tryLock() is implemented using  pthread_mutex_trylock. I think thats how it is.

Comment: the only distribution problem is that you have to include the LGPL license along with your code when you dynamically link to the qt libraries (this is assuming you're using the open sourced and not commercial source version). On windows, if you're unsure which DLLS you'd need inorder to distribute, use `depends.exe` and it will tell you exactly!

http://www.dependencywalker.com/

Answer (score 5):

But you have to know what QThreads use event loop for managment it, so you can't just kill thread like with pthread. If threads do long and hard work, it's not possible to stop it while it not to be released. In some case it's important.

Answer (score 2):

I think at the heart of things, `QThread` under linux uses `pthread`. I'm not sure what is under the hood for the Windows side of it. Unless there are some some specific `pthread` API functions that you need that aren't available with `QThread`, I would stick with `QThread` just to benefit from the portability that it will give you. I wouldn't expect there to be any significant performance difference. `Qthread` will also allow you to use the signal/slot mechanism across thread boundaries.